# How to Average the NVARCHAR in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Anyone! Help me with this problem.
I can't average this data in sql server because its a nvarchar.

```
| Server | Roundtrip | Site |
    A        340ms      QW
    A        400ms      QW
    A        350ms      QW
    B        300ms      QW
    B        400ms      QW
    B        350ms      QW
    C        340ms      QW
    C        400ms      QW
    C        350ms      QW
    D        340ms      QW
    D        400ms      QW
    D        350ms      QW
    A        340ms      WQ
    A        400ms      WQ
    A        350ms      WQ
    B        340ms      WQ
    B        400ms      WQ
    B        350ms      WQ
    C        340ms      WQ
    C        400ms      WQ
    C        350ms      WQ
    D        340ms      WQ
    D        400ms      WQ
    D        350ms      WQ
```

Is it possible to average this data without removing the ms?
Also by filtering it like this

```
| Server | Ave-Roundtrip-WQ | Ave-Roundtrip-WQ |
    A           363.33             363.33
    B           363.33             363.33   
    C           363.33             363.33   
    D           363.33             363.33
```

Anyone.. Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do arithmetic operations on data that can't be converted to a numeric type. Your only solution is to get that numeric value from your data.

To get the numeric value of `Roundtrip`, you need to remove `'ms'`. You can do this using `REPLACE`. Then cast the result to a numeric datatype. Then, to put the average of `'WQ'` and `'QW'` on separate columns, you need to do conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97427/1/0)

```
SELECT
    Server,
    [Ave-Roundtrip-WQ]  = AVG(CASE WHEN Site = 'WQ' THEN CAST(REPLACE(Roundtrip, 'ms', '') AS NUMERIC (30, 4)) END),
    [Ave-Roundtrip-QW]  = AVG(CASE WHEN Site = 'QW' THEN CAST(REPLACE(Roundtrip, 'ms', '') AS NUMERIC (30, 4)) END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Server
```

**RESULT**

```
| Server | Ave-Roundtrip-WQ | Ave-Roundtrip-QW |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|      A |       363.333333 |       363.333333 |
|      B |       363.333333 |              350 |
|      C |       363.333333 |       363.333333 |
|      D |       363.333333 |       363.333333 |
```

Comment: Can it be a fixed into 2 decimals?

Comment: What do you mean by fixed decimal? You can just replace the scale and precision when `CAST`ing.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Does this solve your problem though?

Comment: Yah.. I'm just working on how I will turn into two decimal places :)

Comment: Replace the precision with 2 like this `NUMERIC(30, 2)`. Read more on `NUMERIC` [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: Oh.. Thanks. it's a big help :)